# Dynamically design a table layout

Tags: java, android

---

Itemname   ..............................Amount

Milk     75

---

In this I need to set the 75 under the Amount

I tried setWidth
But it collaspe  when I turn my device to landscape

My code is

```
TextRow tr= new TableRow(Mainactivity.this);

TextView tv= new TextView(Mainactivity.this);
tv.setText("milk");
tr.addView(tv)

TextView tv1=new TextView(Mainactivity.this);
 tv1.setText("75");
tr.addView(tv1);
Tab.addView(tr);
```

Help me

Answer (score 0):

> [...] A TableRow should always be used as a child of a TableLayout. If a TableRow's parent is not a TableLayout, the TableRow will behave as an horizontal LinearLayout.

So you should put your TableRow into a TableLayout.